# I want to put a data table in a tab, but I get an error when I run it

Tags: datatable, flet

The error message is 'There was an error while processing your request: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_set_attr_internal'. Here is the code. How can I put a data table in a tab?

```
table = ft.DataTable(
        width=700,
        bgcolor="yellow",
        border=ft.border.all(2, "red"),
        border_radius=10,
        vertical_lines=ft.border.BorderSide(3, "blue"),
        horizontal_lines=ft.border.BorderSide(1, "green"),
        sort_column_index=0,
        sort_ascending=True,
        heading_row_color=ft.colors.BLACK12,
        heading_row_height=100,
        data_row_color={"hovered": "0x30FF0000"},
        show_checkbox_column=True,
        divider_thickness=0,
        column_spacing=200,
        columns=[
            ft.DataColumn(
                ft.Text("Column 1"),
                on_sort=lambda e: print(f"{e.column_index}, {e.ascending}"),
            ),
            ft.DataColumn(
                ft.Text("Column 2"),
                tooltip="This is a second column",
                numeric=True,
                on_sort=lambda e: print(f"{e.column_index}, {e.ascending}"),
            ),
        ],
        rows=[
            ft.DataRow(
                [ft.DataCell(ft.Text("A")), ft.DataCell(ft.Text("1"))],
                selected=True,
                on_select_changed=lambda e: print(f"row select changed: {e.data}"),
            ),
            ft.DataRow([ft.DataCell(ft.Text("B")), ft.DataCell(ft.Text("2"))]),
        ],
    ),
    t = ft.Tabs(
        selected_index=1,
        animation_duration=300,
        tabs=[
            ft.Tab(
                text="Tab 1",
                content=ft.Container(
                    content=table,
                    alignment=ft.alignment.center
                ),
            )
        ],
        expand=1,
    )
    page.add(
        t
    )
```

How can I put a data table in a tab?